# Noughts and Crosses Issue

Tags: c#, xna-4.0

I'm an amateur programmer and I'm working on a simple Noughts and crosses game in XNA Game studio. Right now I'm up to making a left click trigger a move, and it was working.
But when I was transferring the code into two files with the partial class command I accidentally changed the code, and now the right-top corner squares aren't working.
Here is the "update" code, which checks for this:

```
    private void MouseProcess()
    {

        MouseState mstate = Mouse.GetState();
        Mouse_pos = new Vector2(mstate.X, mstate.Y);
        float xpos = mstate.X;
        float ypos = mstate.Y;

        if (mstate.LeftButton.Equals(ButtonState.Pressed))
        {
            if (xpos >= Gamevar[0].Position.X && xpos <= Gamevar[0].Position.X + 72)
            {
                C = 1;
            }

            if (xpos >= Gamevar[1].Position.X && xpos <= Gamevar[1].Position.X + 72)
            {
                C = 2;
            }

            if (xpos >= Gamevar[2].Position.X && xpos <= Gamevar[2].Position.X + 72)
            {
                C = 3;
            }

            if (ypos >= Gamevar[0].Position.Y && xpos <= Gamevar[0].Position.Y + 75)
            {
                R = 1;
            }

            if (ypos >= Gamevar[3].Position.Y && xpos <= Gamevar[3].Position.Y + 75)
            {
                R = 2;
            }

            if (ypos >= Gamevar[6].Position.Y && xpos <= Gamevar[6].Position.Y + 75)
            {
                R = 3;
            }
        }


    }

    private void Turncode()
    {
        switch (turn)
        {
            case true:
                switch (C)
                {
                    case 1:
                        switch (R)
                        {
                            case 1:
                                Gamevar[0].owner = 1;
                                turn = false;
                                C = 0;
                                R = 0;
                                break;
                            case 2:
                                Gamevar[3].owner = 1;
                                turn = false;
                                C = 0;
                                R = 0;
                                break;
                            case 3:
                                Gamevar[6].owner = 1;
                                turn = false;
                                C = 0;
                                R = 0;
                                break;
                        }
                        break;

                    case 2:
                        switch (R)
                        {
                            case 1:
                                Gamevar[1].owner = 1;
                                turn = false;
                                C = 0;
                                R = 0;
                                break;
                            case 2:
                                Gamevar[4].owner = 1;
                                turn = false;
                                C = 0;
                                R = 0;
                                break;
                            case 3:
                                Gamevar[7].owner = 1;
                                turn = false;
                                C = 0;
                                R = 0;
                                break;
                        }
                        break;

                    case 3:
                        switch (R)
                        {
                            case 1:
                                Gamevar[2].owner = 1;
                                turn = false;
                                C = 0;
                                R = 0;
                                break;
                            case 2:
                                Gamevar[5].owner = 1;
                                turn = false;
                                C = 0;
                                R = 0;
                                break;
                            case 3:
                                Gamevar[8].owner = 1;
                                turn = false;
                                C = 0;
                                R = 0;
                                break;
                        }
                        break;
                }

                break;
            case false:
                switch (C)
                {
                    case 1:
                        switch (R)
                        {
                            case 1:
                                Gamevar[0].owner = 2;
                                turn = true;
                                C = 0;
                                R = 0;
                                break;
                            case 2:
                                Gamevar[3].owner = 2;
                                turn = true;
                                C = 0;
                                R = 0;
                                break;
                            case 3:
                                Gamevar[6].owner = 2;
                                turn = true;
                                C = 0;
                                R = 0;
                                break;
                        }
                        break;

                    case 2:
                        switch (R)
                        {
                            case 1:
                                Gamevar[1].owner = 2;
                                turn = true;
                                C = 0;
                                R = 0;
                                break;
                            case 2:
                                Gamevar[4].owner = 2;
                                turn = true;
                                C = 0;
                                R = 0;
                                break;
                            case 3:
                                Gamevar[7].owner = 2;
                                turn = true;
                                C = 0;
                                R = 0;
                                break;
                        }
                        break;

                    case 3:
                        switch (R)
                        {
                            case 1:
                                Gamevar[2].owner = 2;
                                turn = true;
                                C = 0;
                                R = 0;
                                break;
                            case 2:
                                Gamevar[5].owner = 2;
                                turn = true;
                                C = 0;
                                R = 0;
                                break;
                            case 3:
                                Gamevar[8].owner = 2;
                                turn = true;
                                C = 0;
                                R = 0;
                                break;
                        }
                        break;
                }

                break;

        }
    }
```

Its not very complex but Gamevar[1],[2] and[5] do not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a for loop to iterate through the squares to get the position of the cursor.
(note your values for `C` and `R` will be one less than in your original code.)

You can then get the index of you cell in your one-dimensional array with the equation `(R*3)+C`.

```
private void MouseProcess()
{
    MouseState mstate = Mouse.GetState();
    Mouse_pos = new Vector2(mstate.X, mstate.Y);
    float xpos = mstate.X;
    float ypos = mstate.Y;

    if (mstate.LeftButton.Equals(ButtonState.Pressed))
    {
        for (int i=0; i<3; i++)
        {
            if (xpos >= Gamevar[i].Position.X && xpos <= Gamevar[i].Position.X + 72)
            {
                C = i;
            }
            if (ypos >= Gamevar[i*3].Position.Y && ypos <= Gamevar[i*3].Position.Y + 75)
            {
                R = i;
            }
        }
    }
}

private void Turncode()
{
    if (turn==true)
    {
        Gamevar[(R*3)+C].owner=1;
    }
    else
    {
        Gamevar[(R*3)+C].owner=2;
    }
    turn=!turn; //toggle to the other person's turn
    C=0;
    R=0;
}
```

If ever your code gets repetitive, try using a loop or finding an equasion to do the work for you.

Answer (score 0):

Inside `ProcessMouse`, your `if` statements checking `ypos` are actually looking at `xpos` in the second operand to the `&&`:

e.g.

```
if (ypos >= Gamevar[0].Position.Y && xpos <= Gamevar[0].Position.Y + 75)
{
    R = 1;
}
```

should be:

```
if (ypos >= Gamevar[0].Position.Y && ypos <= Gamevar[0].Position.Y + 75)
{
    R = 1;
}
```

and so on for the following two `if` statements.

Aside from that, you will probably benefit from refactoring your code to have a method for calculating the index of the square clicked on, rather than storing the column and row in separate variables and having nested switch statements.

Comment: Thank you for your help,
I'm a beginner right now, but ill look into that later